Grassmann numbers and fermion creation and annihilation operators
Reading Fradkin's book on Condensed Matter Physics, I encountered Grassmann numbers. In the following $\hat\Psi$ and $\hat\Psi^\dagger$ are the fermion annihilation and creation operators whereas $\Psi$ and $\bar\Psi$ are Grassmann numbers.
As per page 44 (chapter 3) of Fradkin's book:
$$ \left(1 - \Psi \hat{\Psi}^{\dagger}\right) = \exp\left({-\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}}\right)$$
I realize that the Taylor expansion of a Grassmann function does not go beyond the linear term but how does one verify that in the presence of the creation operator?
Apart from the usual creation and annihilation and the the Grassman anticommutation constraints, we also have:
$$\left\{\Psi, \hat\Psi\right\} = 0 \quad and \quad \left(\Psi \hat\Psi\right)^\dagger=\hat\Psi^\dagger\bar\Psi$$
As I tried it, the series expansion of the exponential would be:
$$\exp\left({-\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)^n}{n!} $$
I am partly confused by whether the second power term should be written as
$$\left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)^2 = \left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)\left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)$$
or as
$$\left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)^2 = \left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)^{*}\left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right).$$

Hi. Are you certain that all the info you provide are consistent with the book you mention?

Usually we take the Grassmann "variables" and the Fermi annihlation and creation opertors to anticommute so all the terms you are worrying about are zero because they have two $\Psi$s.

@mikestone So does that mean ${\Psi,\hat\Psi^\dagger} = 0$ too?

Yes. all Grassmans anticommute with all fermion operators.

The correct expression is
$$\left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)^2 = \left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)\left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right).$$
Do notice, however, that
\begin{align}
\left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)^2 &= \left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right)\left(\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\right), \\
&= \Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}\Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger}, \\
&= - \Psi \Psi \hat\Psi^{\dagger} \hat\Psi^{\dagger}, \\
&= 0.
\end{align}
Similar arguments apply to all $n > 1$.

Fradkin introduces Grassmann numbers rather handwavingly. Is there a slightly more rigorous text suitable for physicists that you can recommend?

@RWalser Probably the book by Nakahara. I believe it is called Geometry, Topology, and Physics
